# raspi cam interfacing into matlab 2013a

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, wifi

I know the raspi command is only available for the 2014a version since the version I have is 2013a I suppose there should be a workaround.

My goal is something like this, This is purely experimental and done only to learn. I am trying to acquire images(or video stream, yet to decide on that. But currently I have a video stream) from the raspberry camera and send them to the laptop via wifi. Then The image processing toolbox will process the image and send back some data to the raspberrypi again. According to these data the motors connected to the raspberrypi via an L293D chip will drive the raspberry pi.

I said images because I need to calibrate the motor driver as efficient as it could. Raspberry pi will send and image, then matlab will process it and send the data back with an OK signal. Then only the raspberry pi will send the other image. I am currently sending the video stream with motion, I hope it could be configured to send stills as well, otherwise, I’d be using mjpeg_streamer.

How would I open a stream with a url like `http://192.168.1.5:8081/`? Giving the URL to imread doesn't work. And if i can't do that how would I configure the raspberry pi or `motion` to have another kind of url, where there is a .jpg extension at the end?

PS: This is a line following robot. I have very little knowledge in OpenCV, I shall try this on the raspberry pi itself without using the laptop when I get a good idea about openCV.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just installed apache2 on the RPI and feeling stupid after not thinking it over before posting the question. How ever, there still is a little bit of a lag and I don't know how to open the web stream from matlab